# Any measurable function onto $[0,1]$ can be made into a uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am asking this question in order to see that a uniform probability distribution on $[0,1]$ is the distribution of 'many' possible uniform random variables; not just the trivial identity function from $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)\rightarrow([0,1],\mathcal{B})$. I take **any** measurable function $U$ on **any** measurable space $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ that maps onto $([0,1],\mathcal{B})$. I reduce my sigma-algebra $\Sigma$ into the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ generated by the $U$-pullbacks of Borel sets in $[0,1]$. Clearly my $U$ is still measurable. I now define the probability measure $P$ on $\Omega$ by $$P(U^{-1}(B)):=\lambda(B)$$ and 'sigma-extending' to whole of $\mathcal{F}$.

Now look at $U$ as a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Then the distribution of $U$ that it induces on ($[0,1],\mathcal{B})$ is the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. Does this look alright? Would love any input on this.

Comment: What you have done is right.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks!